# Terraform throwing error:error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

I was facing issue with running aws command via cli with certificate issue. So as per some blogs, I was trying to fix the issue using setx AWS_CA_BUNDLE "C:\data\ca-certs\ca-bundle.pem" command.

Now even after I removed the variable AWS_CA_BUNDLE from my aws configure file, terraform keeps throwing the below error on terraform apply.

Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: loading configuration: open C:\data\ca-certs\ca-bundle.pem: The system cannot find the path specified.

Can someone please tell me where terraform/aws cli is taking this value from and how to remove it? I have tried deleting the entire aws config and credential files still this error is thrown, uninstall aws cli and reinstalling.

If its set in some system/environment variable, can you please tell me how to reset it to default value?

Comment: What is the error? Can you add that to the question?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to add ca_bundle variable to config file is wrong.
Your config file should look like this

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
ca_bundle = dev/apps/ca-certs/cabundle-2019mar05.pem
```

But as I understand you want to use environment variable (AWS_CA_BUNDLE).

**AWS_CA_BUNDLE:**
Specifies the path to a certificate bundle to use for HTTPS certificate validation.
If defined, this environment variable overrides the value for the profile setting ca_bundle. You can override this environment variable by using the --ca-bundle command line parameter.

I would suggest remove environment variable (AWS_CA_BUNDLE) and add ca_bundle to config file. The delete **.terraform** folder and run **terraform init**

Answer (score 1):

Go environment variables and delete the environment variable created by AWS_CA_BUNDLE. Shut down Terminal and again start. Run the commands now it will work properly.